# Count Male and Female who scored greater than average marks

Tags: mysql, sql

This question was asked in a practice Test, and I am new to SQL.

Question was to determine the average marks scored by the male and female students. Also, you are required to determine the count of the students whose score is greater than their gender's average.

Table Description:

```
=======================
| Field    |  Type    |  
=======================
| RollNo   |  int     |
| Name     |  text    |
| Gender   |  text    |
| Score    |  text    |
=======================
```

Example Input:

```
=========================================
| RollNo   |  Name   | Gender |  Score  |
=========================================
| 101      |  John   |   M    |  85     |
| 102      |  Tracy  |   F    |  79     |
| 103      |  Jake   |   M    |  92     |
| 104      |  Edgar  |   M    |         |
| 105      |  Monica |   F    |  25     |
| 106      |  Alicia |   F    |  50     |
| 107      |  Yash   |   M    |  68     |
=========================================
```

Output:

```
=================================
| Gender   |  Count |  AvgScore |
=================================
| Female   |  1     |   51      |
| Male     |  2     |   81      |
=================================
```

Output Explantion:
There are 4 male student but 1 student didn't attempt so we ignore that null value.
So avg score of male is (85 + 92 + 68)/3 = 81.67(take only integer value)
and only 2 student has score above 81

This I tried just for counting number of male and female:

```sql
SELECT
CASE WHEN S.Gender="M" then "Male" else "Female" END AS Gender
COUNT(Gender) as Count
FROM Students AS S
GROUP BY Gender
```

I don't know where to put `AVG` function. Should I use nested queries? or is there anything that I pre-query the avg then compare with every rows?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: I am using MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do two computations.  The first is determining the averages you need. The second is retrieving the rows with those averages available. The trick you need is to use a subquery for the first computation, and JOIN it for the second computation.

Here's the first computation formulated as a subquery.

```
               SELECT Gender, AVG(Score) AvgScore
                 FROM scores
                GROUP BY Gender
```

That needs to be joined to your details like this.

```
   SELECT avg.Gender, avg.AvgScore,
          SUM(scores.Score > avg.AvgScore) AboveAverageCount
     FROM (
               SELECT Gender, AVG(Score) AvgScore
                 FROM scores
                GROUP BY Gender
          ) avg
     JOIN scores ON avg.Gender = scores.Gender
    GROUP BY Gender
```

See this.  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jTWnYkAzRfMVkdkM3ve68R/0

The `AVG()` function omits NULL values automatically.

The `SUM()` I suggest works because comparison expressions like `score > AvgScore` have a value of either 1 for true, or 0 for false. That's a MySQL quirk, and doesn't work in other SQL dialects.

Comment: Thanks you for clear and clean explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The AVG should be included in the select statement, together with gender. For example

```
SELECT 
  S.Gender,
  a.avg_score,
  SUM(S.score > a.avg_score) as counts
FROM scores S
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT
     Gender,
     AVG(S.Score) AS avg_score
  FROM scores AS S
  GROUP BY S.Gender) a
USING(Gender)
WHERE S.Score IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Comment: It's giving me wrong answer. It is counting total number of male and female. [https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/emK7DYnhwzbwh8Q4UjQJFr/0](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/emK7DYnhwzbwh8Q4UjQJFr/0)

Comment: You are right, I have updated the query. I missed that the count should calculate only those above the gender's average

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytical function `avg` as follows:

```
Select gender,
       Count(case when score > avg_score_gender then 1 end) as cnt,
       avg_score_gender as avg_score
(Select t.*,
       Avg(score) over (partition by gender) as avg_score_gender
  From t) t
Group by gender, avg_score_gender
```

Comment: This is new method to me. I am getting error [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6MftxstDD8GeQCie8hZrUU/0). Can you help me to learn something new. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT CASE WHEN scores.Gender="M" then "Male" else "Female" END AS Gender,
          SUM(scores.Score > avg.AvgScore) Count, floor(avg.AvgScore) as avgScore
     FROM (
               SELECT Gender, AVG(Score) AvgScore
                 FROM scores
                GROUP BY Gender
          ) avg
     JOIN scores ON avg.Gender = scores.Gender
    GROUP BY scores.Gender order by avg.AvgScore ASC
```

Comment: use floor method for take integer part only and use order by for ascending order

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.